# Small Language Parse Stuck in Loop

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I've been working on a small vector manipulation language recently in Haskell, and I'm stuck on the parser. The syntax of the language is basically as follows:

- All numbers are floats. Acceptable syntaxes are `1`, `3.7`, `-8.`, etc.
- Vectors are comma separated and enclosed in brackets
- Variables are either a single character or multiple characters enclosed in braces (i.e. `[1, 7, -3.2]`, `[x,y]`)
- Function application is left associative and represented by two adjacent expresssions (i.e. `f[1,2,3]`, `{reduce}+0[9,3-7]`)
- Whitespace is ignored

In BNF (I apologize if there are errors in this; I don't use BNF often):

```
<expr> ::= <parens> | <app> | <var> | <num> | <vect>
<subexpr> ::= <parens> | <var> | <num> | <vect>

<parens> ::= "(" <spaces> <expr> <spaces> ")"
<app> ::= <expr> <spaces> <subexpr>
<var> ::= "{" <varchars> "}" | <varchar>
<num> ::= ...
<vect> ::= "[" <spaces> <commasep> <spaces> "]"

<spaces> ::= <spaces> " " | ""
<varchar> ::= "A" | "B" | ... | "a" | "b" | ... | "!" | "@" | ...
<varchars> ::= <varchars> <varchar> | <varchar>
<commasep> ::= <commasep> <spaces> "," <spaces> <expr> | <expr>
```

Everything works fine until I try to add function application, then the parser gets stuck in an infinite loop, even if the input string is just a number. I assume it has something to do with the first line of the `funcApp` parser, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

(For simplicity's sake, I've excluded the evaluator and simplified 'Expression.hs', but 'Parse.hs' and the `Expression` datatype are pretty much as-is)

**Parse.hs:**

```
module Parse
       (
       ) where

import Data.Functor
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Vector as Vec
import Text.Parsec hiding (many, optional, (<|>))

import Expression (Expression)
import qualified Expression as Expr

expr :: Parsec [Char] u Expression
expr = try (funcApp <* eof) <|>
       (subexpr <* eof)

subexpr = try var  <|>
          try numLit <|>
          vectLit


numLit = do
  s <- option 1 (char '-' *> return (-1))
  a <- some digit
  b <- option "0" (char '.' *> many digit)
  let x = sum $ zipWith (*) [10**x | x <- [0,1..]]
          $ map (read . (:[])) $ reverse a
  let y = sum $ zipWith (*) [10**x | x <- [-1,-2..]]
          $ map (read . (:[])) b
  return $ Expr.Number $ s * (x + y)

vectLit = do
  char '[' ; spaces
  xs <- expr `sepBy` (spaces *> char ',' <* spaces)
  spaces ; char ']'
  return $ Expr.Vector $ Vec.fromList xs

var = fmap Expr.Variable $
      ((:[]) <$> oneOf cs) <|> (char '{' *> many (oneOf cs) <* char '}')
  where cs = ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['a'..'z'] ++ "!@#$%^&*_+~-=,./<>?|;:"

funcApp = do
  a <- expr
  spaces
  b <- subexpr
  return $ Expr.FunctionApplication a b
```

**Expression.hs**

```
module Expression
       (
         Expression(..)
       ) where

data Expression = Number               Float
                | Vector               (Vector Expression)
                | PrimitiveFunction    (Expression -> Expression)
                | Function             Expression Expression
                | Variable             String
                | FunctionApplication  Expression Expression
                | Error                String
```

Comment: Try inlining the definition of `expr`: `funcApp = FunctionApplication <$> (try (funcApp <* eof) ...) <*> ...`. In order for the parser `funcApp` to succeed, first the parser `funcApp <* eof` must be at least *tried*, but in order to even *try* the parser `funcApp <* eof`, you must first try the parser `funcApp`. Then you're right back where you started. Essentially this is like defining `let x = y + 1; y = x * 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at function `chainl`? It can be used to construct parsers for left recursive productions in a grammar. I believe that it should solve your problem with function application.

I haven't ghc installed where I'm now, so cannot test your code. But, I can give some generic directions on how to solve your problem.

**Solution 1:**

A solution using `chainl` would be like:

```
funApp = chainl1 expr (return App)
```

where `expr` is your expression parser and `App` is the construction for function application.

**Solution 2:**

Other possibility is to use `many` in combination with `foldl`:

```
funApp = foldl1 App <$> many1 expr
```

the idea is that `many1` will produce a list of parsing results of `expr` and they
will be combined using `App` by function `foldl1`.

Hope that his would help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. One question though. Using either of those techniques, wouldn't `funApp` match on a single instance of `expr`?

Comment: Also, I just tested your code, and it still freezes.

Comment: Hi! Could you please post the missing definitions (Expression)? Usually such things works nicely when I had to deal with left recursive grammars. Also, do you mind in post the grammar of your language?